# Entity Framework 4: Best practices in searching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 3 Application with EF4. I have about 50,000 entities and I'm querying them through LINQ to find what matches best with the given search criteria. There are multiple search criterion (up to about 12) and these are matcheon a step by step basis.

Ex: 50,000 students

1. Get the students within the age range -> A
2. From A, get the students who are male -> B
3. From B, get students who are enrolled to course CS101 -> C

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step by step doesn't mean a lot for SQL and your linq query will be transformed to sql to query the db...

so

```
//I'm a IQueryable
    var queryableStudents = 
       students.Where(m => 
                         m.Age > 10 &&
                         m.Gender == 'm' &&
                         m.CourseList.Any(x => x.Name == 'CS101');

//I'm no more an IQueryable
    var result = queryableStudents.ToList();//the query will be sent to db and result returned.
```

But if  search criteria are optional, you can do

```
//I'm a IQueryable
var queryableStudents = students;

if (searchCriteria.Age > 0)
//I'm still a IQueryable
  queryableStudents = queryableStudents.Where(m => m.Age => searchCriteria.Age);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.Gender))
//I'm still a IQueryable
  queryableStudents = queryableStudents.Where(m => m.Gender == searchCriteria.Gender);
//Now  I'm no more an IQueryable
var result = queryableStudents.ToList()//the query will be sent to db and result returned.
```

If you want a "REAL" step by step, (showing results for each step), you can do

```
//I'm not an IQueryable
    var a= students.Where(m => m.Age > 10).ToList();//you will get all students from your db who respect your first criterion, and then work on an IEnumerable, not an IQueryable.

//I'm not  IQueryable
    var b= a.Where(m => m.Gender == 'm');

//I'm not an IQueryable
    var c= b.Where(m => m.CourseList.Any(x => x.Name == "CS101");
```

Comment: You can extend this approach by writing query extensions to allow reuse of small query snippets (up to a point - if you have custom methods it gets more complicated). See Jimmy Bogard's blog for an example of this: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/ (and the Ayende articles it references)

Comment: m => m.Age => searchCriteria.Age ? shouldnt this check if an age is into the range?

Comment: @MeNoMore well it's just an example, not an exact answer on all criterions. In fact ,yes, this should be something like `m.Age >=searchCriteria.MinAge && m.Age <= searchCriteria.MaxAge`

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = from s in students 
        where ((s.age < max) && (s.age > min)) 
        select s;
var B = from a in A
        where (a.gender.Equals("Male")) 
        select a;
var C = from b in B
        where (b.EnrolledCourses().Contains("CS101")) 
        select b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - after some thought I figured out the most effiecient way of doing this is to use something like [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) to index the entries I want.

The given use case is not a very good one for LINQ/C#.